# Objective C - Problem trying to Parse json and building a model

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Hi guys I need help with * OBJECTIVE C *
I am new to Objc - but not to swift.
but I find myself struggling with simple json parse and building a model.

here is an example of the model I am trying to parse.

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "memes": [
        {
            "id": "61579",
            "name": "One Does Not Simply",
            "url": "https://i.imgflip.com/1bij.jpg",
            "width": 568,
            "height": 335,
            "box_count": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "101470",
            "name": "Ancient Aliens",
            "url": "https://i.imgflip.com/26am.jpg",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 437,
            "box_count": 2
        }
        // probably a lot more memes here..
    ]
}
```

}

I want to create a "MemeModel" to this json object.
and parse it on my viewController and then add to my dataSource Array...
could anyone explain me or show me how should it be done.. all the old objc googling didn't help me tho.
thank you!

QTMeme.h file

```
@interface QTMeme : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) QTData *data;

@end

@interface QTData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray<QTMemeResponse *> *memes;

@end

@interface QTMemeResponse : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *url;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;

-(instancetype) initMemesWithImage:(NSString *)url withTitle:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

And this is the QTMeme.m File ..

```
    @implementation QTMeme
@end

@implementation QTData
@end

@implementation QTMemeResponse

-(instancetype) initMemesWithImage:(NSString *)url withTitle:(NSString *)name {
    self = [super init];
    
    if (self) {
        self.url = url;
        self.name = name;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Did you start by creating the class and its properties?

Comment: Why do it in Objc when you can do it in swift?

Comment: @Larme yes I did.. I struggle with the networking here in objc... if anyone can explain or show me how its done it would be a relief..

Comment: Would you share the model? Did you transform the JSON Data into NSArray/NSDictionary/NSString/NSNumber with NSJSONSerialization? What's your attempt?

Comment: @Larme I have edited my question... and added the model I created..

Comment: And where is the `NSData` object that is your JSON, and your NSJSONSerialization call?

Comment: @Larme 
this is where it all starts to confuse me.. I would like to see and example on how to decode this object into an array... I have been struggling to create and understand how its done tho... would appreciate if you could drop an example of how you decode this inside a view controller and add it to "some dataSource" array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's rename your classes, they are misleading:

```
QTMeme -> QTMemeResponse
QTData -> QTMemeResponseData
QTMemeResponse -> QTMeme
```

Now, since we decode objects dictionaries, let's add a `initWithJSONDictionary:` method for each of them.

```
@interface QTMeme : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *url;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
-(instancetype)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
-(instancetype) initMemesWithImage:(NSString *)url withTitle:(NSString *)name;
@end

@interface QTMemeResponseData : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray<QTMeme *> *memes;
-(instancetype)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
@end

@interface QTMemeResponse : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) QTMemeResponseData *data;
-(instancetype)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation QTMemeResponse
-(instancetype)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.data = [[QTMemeResponseData alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict[@"data"]];
    }
    return self;
}
@end

@implementation QTMemeResponseData
-(instancetype)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *jsonDicts = dict[@"memes"];
        _memes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *aJSONDict in jsonDicts) {
            QTMeme *aMeme = [[QTMeme alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:aJSONDict];
            [_memes addObject:aMeme];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
@end

@implementation QTMeme

-(instancetype)initWithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    return [self initMemesWithImage:dict[@"name"] withTitle:dict[@"url"]];
}
-(instancetype) initMemesWithImage:(NSString *)url withTitle:(NSString *)name {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.url = url;
        self.name = name;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The decoding:

```
NSError *decodingError = nil;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&decodingError];

if (decodingError) {
    NSLog(@"Error while decoding JSON: %@ with stringified data: %@", decodingError, [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
} else {
    QTMemeResponse *decoded = [[QTMemeResponse alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:json];
    NSLog(@"decoded: %@", decoded);
}
```

Output:

```
$>decoded: <QTMemeResponse: 0x600001764810>
```

You can see the values in the debugguer, but maybe let's add some useful logs by overriding `description`:

For `QTMemeResponse`:

```
-(NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ data: %@", [super description], self.data];
}
```

For `QTMemeResponseData`:

```
-(NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ memes: %@", [super description], self.memes];
}
```

For `QTMeme`:

```
-(NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ name: %@, url: %@", [super description], self.name, self.url];
}
```

Which output now:

```
$>decoded: <QTMemeResponse: 0x600001764810> data: <QTMemeResponseData: 0x6000017648b0> memes: (
    "<QTMeme: 0x6000015300e0> name: https://i.imgflip.com/1bij.jpg, url: One Does Not Simply",
    "<QTMeme: 0x600001530100> name: https://i.imgflip.com/26am.jpg, url: Ancient Aliens"
)
```

Note that's how you'd have parsed JSON into CustomModel in Swift too before `Codable` using `(NS)JSONSerialization`. Of course, the for loop, could be a `compactMap()`, you'd need to do a lot of `as? [String: Any]`, etc but that's the same idea...